# Do the Followers of the Seven believe in a devil?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Does the faith of the Seven have a 'Satan' figure- someone who tries to tempt the faithful away from the gods and toward sin?

Comment: https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Faith_of_the_Seven - It appears not. People have free will and can choose to ignore the Seven and will likely end up in one of the seven hells if they do.

Comment: https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_of_the_Seven_Hells ?

Comment: @Mithoron Nice one. And from the Seven Hells article in the the ASOIAF wiki: _The Lord of the Seven Hells practices dark arts and commands demons. Smallfolk believe a witch can trade her unborn children to him, in return for being taught sorcery._ This is clearly a Satan-based figure, especially if you take into account that the Faith Of Seven is based on Christianity. I think you should write an answer based on this information.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's debatable. I doubt there's any mention of such belief in TV adaptations.    In The Sworn Sword, [Lord of the Seven Hells](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_of_the_Seven_Hells) is mentioned, but only once and as some demon lord, rather  then a great force tempting men. Overall, while various vague mentions of "demons" are present, there's no "devils".

Other than that, there are numerous evil deities in other religions, even [Stranger of the Seven](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stranger_(the_Seven)) is a dark, "angel of death"-like figure, except there seems to be no angels, as well as no devils, in this religion.